# Excel delete empty rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to delete rows which are completely empty. For example, I have a sheet with at least 10 rows and 5 columns. Some rows don't have a value in `ColumnA` but do in `ColumnB`. Other rows have no value in any column. How can I delete those rows with no value at all but keep those rows with a value in at least one column?

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer as continuation to your example. Goto a new column (6th Column), write formula using `CONCATENATE` function to concatenate values of columns 1 to 5. Drag the formula to all rows of column 6. Now you can see that column 6 will have blank values only if columns 1 to 5 are blank. Now you can `autofilter` column 6 to show only blank values and delete those rows.

Comment: + 1 One can also use `=CountA()`