# How can I delete rows containing the same entry -excel

Tags: excel

At work, I keep exporting the same excel document and I have to delete the empty rows manually every time. I was wondering if there was a way to delete them automatically. I also want to delete rows containing certain words if that is possible. Here is an example of the document I export: [image]I wish to delete the rows 3-4-5, 8-9-10-11-12-13, 17-18-19-20-21-22 in this example.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it. No, we won't write the code to do it for you. We help fix code you've written, not do your job for you.

Comment: Can I have a link to the previously aked asked question?
I couldn't find it that's the only reason I asked.
thanks

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576894/excel-delete-empty-rows) is relevant, also look at `countif()` and `countifs()` functions in excel

Comment: Alright I'll check it out.

Comment: Half a million [results](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=excel%20delete%20rows%20containing%20the%20same%20entry&oq=excel%20delete%20rows%20containing%20the%20same%20entry&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.6895j0j7). Edit: first one looks promising from the title alone...

Comment: Yeah I found that link too and followed the options it offered me.
The problem is it seems to only delete columns and not rows *unless I misunderstood the message*.
All I want to do is make excel go through all my selected rows and delete those that don't have a value.

Comment: @Imran  Great link thanks. I'll try it it should work.